# Eclipse, Orion, OSGi development environment setup (Maqetta)

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, eclipse-orion, maqetta

I want to build upon an open-source project.

Need help with the setup (development environment in Eclipse)!

These are the instructions on github: [Maqetta with Orion Developer Setup](http://github.com/maqetta/maqetta/wiki/Maqetta-with-Orion-Developer-Setup).

In Eclipse Neon bundles verification fails.

In Eclipse Juno bundles are ok, but I still get some exceptions:

```
22:33:20,996 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
22:33:20,996 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
22:33:20,996 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [bundleresource://42.fwk1749186397:1/logback.xml]
22:33:21,004 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@3ca154f5 - URL [bundleresource://42.fwk1749186397:1/logback.xml] is not of type file
22:33:21,020 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
22:33:26,027 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
22:33:26,030 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
22:33:26,079 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
22:33:26,079 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
22:33:26,079 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
22:33:26,080 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.eclipse.orion.server.login] to INFO
22:33:26,080 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.eclipse.orion.server.account] to INFO
22:33:26,080 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.eclipse.orion.server.config] to INFO
22:33:26,080 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to WARN
22:33:26,080 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
22:33:26,081 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@aa9b84d - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

!SESSION 2017-01-09 22:33:15.186 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_112
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.orion.product
Command-line arguments:  -dev file:/Users/ted/Documents/juno-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/maqetta-orion multi user/dev.properties -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -console -data /Users/ted/Documents/juno-workspace/../__maqetta_server_workspace -clean -product org.eclipse.orion.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.orion.server.search 4 0 2017-01-09 22:33:26.349
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.orion.internal.server.search.SearchActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.orion.server.search.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter
    at org.apache.solr.analysis.SynonymFilterFactory.init(SynonymFilterFactory.java:31)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$6.init(IndexSchema.java:931)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$6.init(IndexSchema.java:923)
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:148)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readAnalyzer(IndexSchema.java:941)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.access$100(IndexSchema.java:62)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$1.create(IndexSchema.java:445)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$1.create(IndexSchema.java:435)
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:140)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:480)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:125)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.orion.internal.server.search.SearchActivator.createServer(SearchActivator.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.orion.internal.server.search.SearchActivator.start(SearchActivator.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.SynonymFilter
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 29 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter
    at org.apache.solr.analysis.SynonymFilterFactory.init(SynonymFilterFactory.java:31)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$6.init(IndexSchema.java:931)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$6.init(IndexSchema.java:923)
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:148)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readAnalyzer(IndexSchema.java:941)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.access$100(IndexSchema.java:62)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$1.create(IndexSchema.java:445)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$1.create(IndexSchema.java:435)
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:140)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:480)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:125)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.orion.internal.server.search.SearchActivator.createServer(SearchActivator.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.orion.internal.server.search.SearchActivator.start(SearchActivator.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.SynonymFilter
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 29 more
2017-01-09 22:33:26.511 [Start Level Event Dispatcher] INFO  org.eclipse.orion.server.config - Server configuration file loaded from: /Users/ted/Documents/juno-workspace/maqetta/releng/davinci.releng/orion/builder/rootfiles/maqetta.conf

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-01-09 22:33:26.569
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.orion.server.search_1.0.0.v20130131-0030 [12] is not active.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-01-09 22:33:26.570
!MESSAGE Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

[Maqetta FAQ](http://maqetta.org/faq.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to use [Eclipse Juno for Java EE Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2).

Follow these instructions: [Maqetta with Orion Developer Setup · maqetta/maqetta Wiki](https://github.com/maqetta/maqetta/wiki/Maqetta-with-Orion-Developer-Setup).

And then go to the Run Configurations > Bundles tab > press Add Bundles, and add each of the following bundles:

[image]